# Transpile javascript binaryExpression with + operator to bash equivalent

Tags: javascript, bash, typescript, compiler-construction, transpiler

I am trying to write a PoC typescript/javascript to bash transpiler.
(I have little to no background in writing compilers or transpilers)

I am using the typescript compiler API to lex and generate the Parse Tree.

I am able to convert simple expressions to bash as follows:

```
let a =1 
let b=2;
let c = (a+(b*2));
console.log(c,"d",1);
```

transpiles to:

```sh
a=1
b=2
c=($(($a + ($(($b * 2))))))
echo  "$c" "d" 1
```

But I don't know how to convert the concatenation operator, As there is no concatenation operator in bash and the way you concat in bash is "$word1 $word2".

for example:

```
let strLitIdentifier = "abc"
let a3 = a + ((2*3)+strLitIdentifier)
```

Now the expected output would be:

```
strLitIdentifier="abc"
a3="$a$((2 * 3))$strLitIdentifier"
```

But while iterating and when I am within the BinaryExpression node of (a+?) I don't have a way to realize if the identifier is a number or the output from the right operand is going to be a string. And I can't keep the '+' operator as bash doesn't use '+' for concatenation.

from @Ed Morton's comments, I have been able to make slight progress by using the typeof method but:

```
let a = 1 + 1; #works, output: 2
let b = 1 + "a"; #works, output: 1a
let c = 1 + "1";  #Invalid, output: 2, expected: 11
```

Example Generated Code:

```
function bashtype_is_num {
    local re='^[0-9]+$'
    if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo "NaN"
    else
        echo "NUMBER"
    fi 
}

function bashtype_add_or_concat  {
    if [[ $(bashtype_is_num $1) == "NUMBER" &&  $(bashtype_is_num $2) == "NUMBER" ]]; then
        echo $(($1 + $2))
    else
        echo "$1$2"
    fi
}

a=$(bashtype_add_or_concat 1 1)
b=$(bashtype_add_or_concat 1 "a")
c=$(bashtype_add_or_concat 1 "1")
```

Comment: @EdMorton The thing is I won't know if $word1 & $word2 are strings or numbers till runtime. In JS, "+" works for both add and concat, while in bash, I need to know the operation and operand types in advance (Which isn't possible in JS).

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you, I have updated the question to reflect your ideas.

Comment: I actually meant for you to employ a typeof() operation when generating the bash code. Once it's in bash it's too late as everything's passed around as a string unless specifically declared as a number (`declare -i var`) and it's type is determined by the context in which it's used at any given time so there's no way to differentiate `foo 1` from `foo "1"` inside function `foo`.

Comment: "I am trying to write a PoC typescript/javascript to bash transpiler" Which one is it - JavaScript or TypeScript? JavaScript doesn't have static types, but TypeScript does. So if it's TypeScript, you can just make decisions based on the static type (and, I guess, reject programs that use `any`).